# Send email through Mailgun using Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, mailgun, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to setup `Cloud Code` in `Parse` for `Mailgun` to send emails. I have successfully done with writing the Java Script code mentioned below

```
Parse.Cloud.define("SendEmail", function(request, response) {

    var Mailgun = require('mailgun');
    Mailgun.initialize('myDomainName', 'MyKey');

    Mailgun.sendEmail({
            to: request.object.get("to") , 
            from: "info@sample.com",
            subject: request.object.get("subject"),
            text: request.object.get("text")
        },{
        success: function() {
            response.success(request.params);
            console.log("--email sent - success");
            console.log(request.params);
        },
        error: function() {

            console.log("--failed to send email - success");
            console.error(request.params);
            response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
        }
    }); 


});
```

But I am continuously getting the following error

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
    at main.js:1:602 (Code: 141, Version: 1.2.20)
2014-08-20 02:05:03.725 PhotoAlert[475:60b] Error : Error Domain=Parse Code=141 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 141.)" UserInfo=0x15ec5b90 {code=141, error=TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
    at main.js:1:602}
```

I am anxiously looking for solution as I am new for Parse/Mailgun and JS too.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that where you have:

```
request.object.get("to")
```

It should be:

```
request.params.to
```

And that goes for all of the parameters that you are passing into the CloudCode Function (to, subject and text).

Being very new to this myself, Im guessing that the error is saying that the is no argument being passed in called "object" therefor there is no "get" method for it.